# MySQL: search keywords in multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I want to search in a MySQL table in two columns for one or more keywords.

I tried this query:

```
select * 
  from table 
 where match(col1, col2) against ('keyword1 keyword 2' with query expansion)
```

But this query does not always gives the right results. Any suggestions?

Comment: please post the complete query you are using for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps:

```
select *, match(col1, col2) 
          against ('keyword1 keyword2' in boolean mode) as relevance
  from content 
 where match(col1, col2) 
       against ('keyword1 keyword2' in boolean mode)
 order by relevance;
```

Compare [results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32e85/1) of this query and the one you wrote above.

Note that using `WITH QUERY EXPANSION` results in a more fuzzy search. From [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-query-expansion.html):

> "It works by performing the search twice, where the search phrase for the second search is the original search phrase concatenated with the few most highly relevant documents from the first search."

Comment: Hi, great!  this is exactly what I was searching for, it works fine!  thanks!

Comment: I'd highly appreciate it, if you could accept my answer and/or up-vote it :D

Comment: Hi Trinimon .. I tried but since I am new I do not yet have the proper reputation to up-vote ...

Comment: Mmmhhh ... but I think you can accept it, can't you? Check _"answer is marked “accepted”: +15 (__+2 to acceptor__) "_ (at http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation); so you gain even 2 reputation ;)